# how to create individual bars in the descending order in proc sgplot?

Tags: sas, sgplot

I created the following graph using `sgplot`

```
proc sgplot data=Colordistricts;
hbar distrct/response=Percent 
group= population;
run;
```

[image]

However, it seems that the individual population groups are arranged in alphabetical order in the graph (Asian followed by Black Color and White).

How do I create this same plot with the population groups in the descending order by percent?

In fact these are districts where the color population is highest. Basically I want to create a graph so that each bar begins with the color population

Comment: Try CategoryOrder or GROUPORDER? What's your version of SAS, the options differ based on your version.

Comment: How should the other population segments be ordered after placing "Color" in the first population position ?  Sorting by a specific percent can disorder the population item (colored bars at different places), and sorting by population item can disorder the percents (jaggy same colored bars)

Comment: @Reeza I have SAS 9.4

Comment: @Richard I want the order to be color, white, black and asian

Comment: @Nathan123 you'd have to provide the exact version, ie 9.4 TS1M5 or M4. There are significant improvements after M3 and in M5.

Comment: @Reeza I have 9.04.01M3P062415

Answer (score 0):

To force a specific group value to the first position you can map the desired group to a new value that will collate first.  Sometimes this is easily done by placing a space character in front of an existing value.

If the group variable is a numeric ID custom formatted to display an associated group label you can create a new version of the custom format to include a 0 id that corresponds to the forced group.   The forced group is mapped to the 0 id.

You would then sort the data in the particular way you need and use SGPLOT `yaxis type=discrete discreteOrder=data;` to force the hbar categories to appear in the particular order.

Here is some sample code to explore.  The final SGPLOT uses the mapping technique to force a particular population segment to appear first.

```
ods html close;

%let path = %sysfunc(pathname(work));
ods html file="&path.\sgplot_hbar.html" gpath="&path.";

proc format;
  value popId
  0 = 'Color'
  1 = 'Asian'
  2 = 'Black'
  3 = 'Color'
  4 = 'White'
;

data have;
  do _n_ = rank('A') to rank('P');
    district = byte (_n_);
    x = 0;
    populationID = 2; percent = ceil(40*ranuni(123)); output;
    x + percent;
    populationID = 3; percent = ceil(40*ranuni(123)); output;
    x + percent;
    if (ranuni(123) < 0.10) then do;
    populationID = 1; percent = ceil(10*ranuni(123)); output;
    x + percent;
    end;
    percent = 100 - x;
    populationID = 4;
    output;
  end;
  keep district populationID percent;
  label
    percent = 'Percent of Total Frequency'
  ;
  format
    populationID popId.
  ;
run;

proc sgplot data=have;
  hbar district
  / group = populationID
    response = percent
  ;
  title j=L 'default group order by populationID value';
  title2 j=L 'districts (yaxis) also implicitly sorted by formatted value';
run;

proc sgplot data=have;
  hbar district
  / group = populationID
    response = percent
    categoryOrder = respAsc
  ;
  title j=L 'categoryOrder: ascending response';
  title2 j=L 'districts (yaxis) also implicitly sorted by min(response)';
run;

proc sgplot data=have;
  hbar district
  / group = populationID
    response = percent
    categoryOrder = respDesc
  ;
  title j=L 'categoryOrder: descending response';
  title2 j=L 'districts (yaxis) also implicitly sorted by descending max(response)';
run;

proc sql;
  create table have2 as
  select 
    case 
      when populationID = 3 then 0 else populationID
    end as hbar_populationID format=popId.
  , *
  from have
  order by 
    hbar_populationID, percent
  ;
quit;

proc sgplot data=have2;
  yaxis type=discrete discreteOrder=data;

  hbar district
  / group = hbar_populationID
    response = percent
  ;

  title j=L 'population seqment ordering is partially forced by tweaking populationID values';
  title2 j=L 'districts in data order per yaxis statement';
run;
```

**Forced groupOrder**

SQL can sort the data in a particular order by using a `case` in the `order by` clause.  You would then use `groupOrder=data` in SGPLOT.

```
proc sql;
  create table have3 as
  select *
  from have
  order by 
    district
  , case 
      when populationID = 3 then 0
      when populationID = 2 then 1
      when populationID = 4 then 2
      when populationID = 1 then 3
      else 99
    end
  ;
quit;

proc sgplot data=have3;
  hbar district
  / group = populationID
    groupOrder = data
    response = percent
  ;

  title j=L 'population seqment ordering is partially forced by tweaking populationID values';
  title2 j=L 'districts in data order per yaxis statement';
run;
```

**Forcing one segment to be first and then the other segments relying on response values**

After mapping populationID 2 to 0 you could force the remaining population segments to be ordered similar to `respAsc` or `respDesc`.  That process would require additional coding to determine new mappings for the other populationID values.  This additional example shows how the global response sum is used to force a descending order on the remaining population segments within a district.

```
proc sql;
  create table way as 
  select populationID, sum(percent) as allPct
  from have
  where populationID ne 3
  group by populationID
  order by allPct descending
  ;

data waySeq;
  set way;
  seq + 1;
run;

proc sql;
  create table have3 as
  select
    have.*
  , case 
      when have.populationID = 3 then 1000 else 1000+seq
    end as hbar_populationID
  from have
  left join waySeq on have.populationID = waySeq.populationID
  order by 
    hbar_populationID, percent
  ;

  create table fmtdata as
  select distinct 
    hbar_populationID as start
  , put(populationID, popId.) as label
  , 'mappedPopId' as fmtname
  from have3;
quit;

proc format cntlin = fmtdata;
run;

%let syslast = have3;

proc sgplot data=have3;
  yaxis type=discrete discreteOrder=data;

  hbar district
  / group = hbar_populationID
    response = percent
    groupOrder = data
  ;

  format hbar_populationID mappedPopId.;

  title j=L 'population seqment ordering is partially forced by tweaking populationID values';
  title2 j=L 'districts in data order per yaxis statement';
run;

title;
```